# Understanding the splitview and tableview controllers with Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uistoryboard, uisplitviewcontroller

new to iOS developing and I'm a bit confused with these two at the moment, I was wondering if anyone could help me out and maybe point me in the right direction if this is not the right way of doing things.

So, I'm making a simple app for iPad in which I'm using the splitview controller with a tableview on the master side, the detail side will be used to show a new view linked to each of the items on the table. These will be sections and each section will have a number of questions with Yes/No/NA buttons for answers.

I've played around with segues and buttons and going from one view to another I'm ok with, I also managed to change the the text in a label to match the item in tableview when selected as a test ([Ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LESVS.png)), the problem comes when trying to load a new view into the detail view when selecting an item from a dynamic table.

Will I need a navigation controller + view controller for each of the 'sections' I plan on adding?(16 so far).

Thanks in advance.

Edit: [Ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFsSs.png)

Edit:

So I'm using separate view controllers for each "section" and I sort of managed to get different views to open when clicking an item in the tableview but the problem I'm having now is that the new view is opening in the masterview and not in detail, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {

         let view2: UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AssemblyCheck")
            self.navigationController!.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)
```

Comment: It depends on how similar or different the data to be displayed is for each section.  At one end of the scale, the data structure is the same but the values are different (like your updated label).  At the other end, the structure is totally different and your detail view will need to swap subviews, possibly each with its own controller.  Not so helpful maybe, but if you'd like to give a concrete example of what you want to display you might get a better answer.

Comment: I will be displaying various questions and possibly images to accompany each section but the structure of each section will differ. I've edited my post and added a screenshot of a storyboard I just made, could you tell me if this is the way to do it if I decide to go with the multiple view option? And if it's not too much to ask could you point me in the right direction as to how I would go about coding the part where an item in the table calls a certain view? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

That depends? If you do not have a navigation controller, you'll not have any "navigation" in the detail view, ie. not be able to use several views and go back and forth between them. If you are sure, you only need one view, you'll be fine with just the viewcontroller. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I think so, so for each view I decide to use I have to have a separate navigation controller as per my second image above?